Looking for help identifying a momentary pushbutton switch
I'm repairing a children's toy and need to replace the switch shown in the attached image (I tried to open it up and repair, but no luck).  It is a momentary pushbutton SPDT switch with 3 thru-hole terminals (on 0.1" spacing) and 2 solderable posts that are part of the housing.  The only marking is what is shown in this image, and I'm unable to identify the logo.  Searched Digikey and Mouser and was unable to find this or equivalent.  I would appreciate any advice.

please add a picture of the switch

It would be unlikely to find a replacement for a proprietary switch in a toy. If the object is to get it working, just wire an external switch across the PCB contacts, or reconstruct your own from spring brass.
